# Bootstrap grid layout wrap columns on desktop

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-website

I have a sidebar that I would like to be a set of columns on mobile, but one column on a desktop or tablet.
[image: Example of desired layout]
I just don't know how to approach this, as [the only documentation bootstrap provides is for the other way around](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#stacked-to-horizontal)

I don't even know what to search, "bootstrap wrap column on wider screen" and the like doesn't turn up useful stuff.

Comment: Post the code that you've tried

Comment: @ZimSystem I don't have code, I do not know how to approach this. I know how to use a basic grid layout, and nothing I know will apply here.

Comment: @ZimSystem Yes, I'm asking how to go from a set of columns on a small screen to a vertical group on bigger screens. That is not a thing bootstrap documentation talks about. It's pretty trivial to wrap a set of columns to a vertical stack when going *down* in size, I'm trying to figure out how to do it when going *up* in size.

Comment: "the only documentation bootstrap provides is for the other way around".. so start with that, post the code and explain specifically why it's not working. You just need to demonstrate some effort to solve it yourself.

Comment: @ZimSystem Yes, in most questions showing some code would be a good suggestion. But in this case, I'm not sure it's possible in bootstrap, and throwing code at the wall won't help if the basic approach is the thing I don't have. All the effort I've put in is trying to find examples, and unless you want my search history, there isn't a good way to demonstrate that effort. Do you actually have any idea how to approach this?

Comment: Yes, there's a simple way to demonstrate. For example, have you tried to get only the mobile layout, or only the desktop layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always start "mobile-first", and create the desired mobile layout. Then make adjustments to get the desired desktop layout.

You could use nesting and the column order (push pull) class to reverse the layout on desktop...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="push-md-9 col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-4">
                    .
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-4">
                    .
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-4">
                    .
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 pull-md-3 col-12">
            .
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/uimdfmnwCC

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. I didn't think about using `col-md-12`. That is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for asking the poor question, I just needed a small nudge. (or just the entire answer, as you kindly provided) Bootstrap 3 version if you want to append it to your answer: http://sprunge.us/eVTd